# SqlService WMI query in PowerShell returns nothing

Tags: sql-server, powershell, wmi

I'm trying to run a simple [Get-WmiObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx) call in PowerShell.

```
Get-WmiObject -computerName $srv -namespace root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement -class SqlService
```

When running under an account that has administrator rights to the remote server I get **no** response. The command does complete, but no data is shown. When running this command under an account that does not have rights to the server I get an "Access Denied" message.

When I run this on the remote server directly I get "Invalid namespace", but the server is definitely our [SQL Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008).

Why doesn't this kind of script return the object as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Get-WmiObject -computerName $srv -namespace root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10 -class SqlService
```

On several machines I have, the namespace is *ComputerManagement10*.

BTW, just in case, you need to find the namespace names:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $srv -NameSpace root\Microsoft\SQLServer -Class "__NAMESPACE" | Select Name
```

The above command will tell you the right namespace names.

Comment: Turned out all I needed to do was add "10" on to the end of ComputerManagement.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked services with `get-service -computername $srv -include “*sql*”`?

I would also check whether the class is present in:

`Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10 -List`